# SQL Server : show a new column that does calculation base on other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server, I have a table which I have simplified as the follow:

```
item ----- order-----Active
-------------------------------    
a-------------1---------true
b-------------2---------false
c-------------3---------true
d-------------4---------true
e-------------5---------false
f-------------6---------true
```

I want to query that return the three columns and an extra column call new-order, which for each item it subtract one for every inactive(Active being false) items that has a order number lower than itself. So the above table will become

```
item ----- ordering-----Active----------NewOrder
-------------------------------------------------    
a-------------1---------true----------1
b-------------2---------false----------2
c-------------3---------true----------2
d-------------4---------true----------3
e-------------5---------false----------4
f-------------6---------true----------4
```

My attempt:

```
Select 
    g.item, g.ordering, g.active,  
    g.ordering - (Select Count(x.ordering)
                  from grocery As x
                  where x.ordering < g.ordering 
                    and x.active = false
                  group by x.ordering) As NewOrder
 From 
     grocery as g
```

which doesn't work because the subquery contain more than one row. But I honestly don't have any idea how to approach this. Is this even possible using just subquery?

Appreciate any advice or help

Edit:

In the database there are more than 6 rows, and not in the correct order.
Basically an item's new order is its own ordering# subtract the number of inactive items whose ordering# is lower than the item's ordering#. 
Again inactive items is items whose active = false.

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to agree with your logic.

Comment: Consider using `JOIN`

Comment: If you literally want `order - 1` you can just do that. However it sounds like maybe you want the previous order (based on numeric ordering) and, I'm guessing, you can't be assured the orders are sequential. This is a leap of logic, but it's something common enough, maybe it's true?

Comment: I've added another explanation at the end. Hope it clear up the confusion

Comment: Look at my answer if it helps

Comment: it's perfect thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following query will give you the result you want, you can omit `NULL` values.
You basically want the `NEWORDER` when `active` is `true` so you can omit `NULL` values for `false`

```
select
a.*,
b.NEWORDER
from
(
select
*
from
test1
)
as a
left join
(
    select [order] as NO,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [order]) as NEWORDER from test1 where active='true'
)
as b
on a.[order]=b.no
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 item   order   active  NEWORDER
-------------------------------------
a       1       true    1
b       2       false   NULL
c       3       true    2
d       4       true    3
e       5       false   NULL
f       6       true    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
SELECT item,
       [order],
       active,
       NewOrder = Sum(t)OVER(ORDER BY [order]) 
FROM   (SELECT *,
               CASE WHEN Lag(Active)OVER(ORDER BY [order]) = 'false' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS t
        FROM   (VALUES ('a',1,'true' ),
                       ('b',2,'false' ),
                       ('c',3,'true' ),
                       ('d',4,'true' ),
                       ('e',5,'false' ),
                       ('f',6,'true' )) tc (item, [order], Active)) a
```

**Result :**

```
+------+-------+--------+----------+
| item | order | active | NewOrder |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
| a    |     1 | true   |        1 |
| b    |     2 | false  |        2 |
| c    |     3 | true   |        2 |
| d    |     4 | true   |        3 |
| e    |     5 | false  |        4 |
| f    |     6 | true   |        4 |
+------+-------+--------+----------+
```